# Aligment is not consistent with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am doing a comment page, but right now I am having the issue that the aligment of the bubble speech gets misaligned.

Example

[image]

I suppose this ca be fixed with CSS, but not quite sure.
I have my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/bSaJc/

Thanks in advance

This is my css

```
.bubble-panel {
    display: inline-block;
    //border: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
}


.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 535px;
height: 130px;
padding: 4px;
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 31px;
-moz-border-radius: 31px;
border-radius: 31px;
border: #46A5E4 solid 9px;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-right: 50px;

}

.bubble p
{
    margin: 10px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 31px 14px 0;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
margin-left: -14px;
bottom: -31px;
left: 20%;
}

.bubble:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 39px 22px 0;
border-color: #46A5E4 transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
margin-left: -22px;
bottom: -48px;
left: 20%;
}
.caption {
    //border: 1px solid red;
    width: 20em;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 50px;
}
.caption h1, .caption h2, .caption h3 {
    font-size: 1.00em;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;

}
```

Comment: What is that orange rectangle div? you need to add `clear:both` for the `div` after that.

Comment: The orange is not part of the image. Was just to show the desaligment

Comment: I think the text lines are pushing the bubbles.

Comment: check your <div> tag, you miss </div> somewhere on the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OrIWAr)

I added `vertical-align: middle;`

```
.bubble {
   position: relative;
   width: 535px;
   height: 130px;
   padding: 4px;
   background: #FFFFFF;
   -webkit-border-radius: 31px;
   -moz-border-radius: 31px;
   border-radius: 31px;
   border: #46A5E4 solid 9px;
   display:inline-block;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-right: 50px;
   vertical-align: middle; /* ADD THIS LINE */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/cfknoop/bSaJc/1/

```
vertical-align:top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` to `.bubble-panel`

```
.bubble-panel {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
height: 250px;
position: relative;
margin: 20px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/OrIWAr/2)